# How to update the student semester after they pass the exam in one go? Already getting list of students

Tags: php, html, mysql

UPDATE: I wish to promoted the passed out students to the next semester wit hthe help of the checkbox. For those students checked, I wish to update the semester. But the student semester gets incremented by 2 instead of 1. e.g. Passed out student from sem 1 gets promoted to sem 3 instead of 2.

Here is the updated code I am using:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
        echo 'Failed to connect';
}
else
{       echo 'Connection established';
        echo "<BR><BR>";
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    //echo 'hello submit<br>';  

    if($_POST['checkbox']){

        //echo 'hello checkbox<br>';    

        for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['checkbox']); $i++)
        {
            echo count($_POST['checkbox']);

            echo '<br>';

            $temp = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['checkbox']),'?'));

            echo $temp;
            echo '<br>';


            $query = "UPDATE students_in_courses

              SET 
                  semester = semester + 1

              WHERE 

                roll_number IN ($temp) ";

            $types = str_repeat('s', count($_POST['checkbox']));

            $prepare = $con-> prepare($query);

            $prepare-> bind_param($types, ...$_POST['checkbox']);

            $prepare->execute();  

            if ($prepare->execute()) { 

            echo 'The student\'s records have been updated.';

            } else {

            echo 'There was a problem updating the student\'s records. <br>';

            }

            $prepare->close();
        }
    }
}



$sql="SELECT * FROM students_in_courses where course_name = 'B.Ed' ";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
        echo 'No records found';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<form name="frmactive" method="post" action="">';

        echo '<table>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><strong>Update multiple rows in mysql with checkbox</strong></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td></td><td><strong>Roll Number</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Course</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Semester</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Year</strong></td></tr>';

        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {


            echo '<tr><td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value = "'.$rows[0].'"></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$rows[0].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$rows[1].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$rows[2].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$rows[3].'</td></tr>';
        }

        echo '<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">';

        echo '</table></form>';
    }   
?>

<html>  

<body>  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide us with some code samples so we can see what you have already tried.  Also, please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Joseph_J I have added the code I have tried so far. I wish to promote batch of students who have passed the exam to next semester in a go by clicking checkboxes. I have been able to get the list of the students but ain't able to update the semester. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated as my assisgnment is due on Tuesday.

Comment: Is the roll number unique

Comment: Yes. The roll number is unique.

Comment: what is the name of the table

Comment: Im sorry  what is column name in the database for the semester and the roll number

Comment: Name of the table is students_in_course which has roll_number, course, semester and year columns. I wish to update only the semester value based on the checkbox checked.

Comment: uhm, your code is completely vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, and script injection/XSS attacks by hackers, you should probably look into htmlentities() and mysqli_read_escape_string() before you're hacked.

Answer (score 0):

I assume That you used POST method :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {    
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value){
            echo "value : ".$value; // Here you get value of checked checkbox.
            // ----- Now Here Execute query to update Semester ------
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this.  You had the right idea, but we are going to specifically tell the query which row to update.  Otherwise the query will just add a semester to every row.

Also, you should use parameterized queries.  I do not use mysqli so I researched it and I think the code I have is correct.  I have not tested it. Parameterizing your queries will prevent sql injection.

Give this a shot, it should work:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  if($_POST['update']){ //<--Check to make sure that update has values in it.

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['update']); $i++){

            //Make sure the table name is correct.
            $query = "UPDATE students_in_course

              SET 
                  semester = semester + 1

              WHERE 

                roll_number = ? ";

            //We are going to use paramterized query stucture.  This 
            //will prevent sql injection.    
            $prepare = $con->prepare($query);
            $prepare->bind_param('s', $_POST['update'][$i]);
            $prepare->execute();  

            if ($prepare->execute()) { 

            echo 'Student #' . $_POST['update'][$i] . ' was successfully updated. <br>';

            } else {

              echo 'There was a problem inserting student # ' . $_POST['update'][$i] . ' into your database. <br>';

             }

            $prepare->close();

        }

  }

}
```

The method above loops through each student that was checked.  On each iteration it makes a separate query for that individual student.

A more advanced way would be to make one query using the $_POST['update'] array directly to expand the query with the WHERE IN clause.  This will update all students that were selected using just one query.

Like so:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  if($_POST['update']){ //<--Check to make sure that update has values in it.

      $clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['update']), '?')); //create 3 question marks        
      //Make sure the table name is correct.
      $query = "UPDATE students_in_course

        SET 

        semester = semester + 1

        WHERE 

        roll_number IN ($clause) ";

        $types = str_repeat('s', count($_POST['update'])); //create 3 "s" or for bind_param.

        $prepare = $con->prepare($query);
        $prepare->bind_param($types, ...$_POST['update']);
        $prepare->execute();  

        if ($prepare->execute()) { 

        echo 'The student\'s records have been updated.';

        } else {

        echo 'There was a problem updating the student\'s records. <br>';

        }

        $prepare->close();

  }

}
```

I used this page to research prepared statements with mysqli.  There is a bunch of information and examples on this page.  You should definitely take a look at it.

https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @Sandeep  I made an error.. I have fixed it.  Current code is current.

Comment: ... inevitably.

Comment: @Joseph_J I really appreciate the efforts you have made in response to the dilema I was having. All thank to your help, I am able to promote the passed out students to the next semester with the help of the checkbox. The only thing is that they get promoted by the increment of 2 instead of 1. e.g. Student in semester 1 gets promoted to sem 3  instead of sem 2. I have updated the code with the current code.

Comment: @Sandeep  Glad you making some progress.  The reason that you are still having problems is because the query you are using is still inside a loop.  Remove the for loop and I have a feeling it will work just fine.  Remember that query is designed to update all students with just one query.  If it loops it will update the query for every iteration of the loop. Cheers.

Comment: @Joseph_J I am very greatful to your for all of your help. You're a saviour. I was strugging with this query for the last few days. Now that it is all sorted out, I feel relieved. Again, big thank you. You're a rockstar!